# django restframework - Serializer for creating m2m relationship

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, m2m

I am using `django-restframework` for my API. I created a serializer which should list my objects and should be able to create them.

I have a `Contact` entity and `Product`. There is a standard m2m between it for the `likes`.

Here's my model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    products_of_interest = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="interested_contacts")
```

My serializer is as simple as it gets:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

When I list my contacts via this serializer I get all my contact objects with an array of product ids - awesome:

```
"products_of_interest": [
        1,
        2
    ]
```

Now, when I want to create a contacts and populate the m2m, I get the following (via my Chrome Postman and form-data):

- Send products_of_interest = 1 --> works (!!!) but just for one product!
- Send products_of_interest = [1,2] --> needs pk and not unicode
- Send products_of_interest = 1;2 --> needs pk and not unicode
- Send products_of_interest[0] = 1, products_of_interest[1] = 2 --> nothing is done at all

I have some experience with serializers, so I thought, maybe I need to tell the serializer, that I want to give him more than one product. So I added this in my serializer:

```
products_of_interest = ProductSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=False)
```

Now I get this error:

> "<Contact:  >" needs to have a value for field "contact" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

I'm totally lost now. What can I do? It can't be that I need to override standard rfw-functions for saving a damn easy m2m, can it?

Comment: Try using [HyperLinkRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#hyperlinkedrelatedfield). The last time I ran into a similar problem, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16181765/2131133) answer to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Django and drf are you using? I cannot reproduce your errors using Django 1.7 and drf 2.4.2. Here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    pass


class Contact(models.Model):
    products_of_interest = models.ManyToManyField(Product,
        related_name="interested_contacts")
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Contact
from rest_framework import serializers


class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Contact
from .serializers import ContactSerializer

class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'contacts', views.ContactViewSet, 'contacts')
urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]

./manage.py shell
>>> from m2m_test.models import Product
>>> for i in range(3): Product.objects.create()
...
<Product: Product object>
<Product: Product object>
<Product: Product object>
>>>
```

And then in the web frontend at `http://localhost:8000/contacts/`:

POST with Raw Data form:
    {
        "products_of_interest": [1, 2, 3]
    }

-> just works.

Comment: thanks so far! but the thing is that I also send files so I need the form-data... any ideas what I can do about this?

Comment: Well, someone had a similar problem some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291466/django-rest-framework-file-upload-with-nested-writable-serializers ;). Afaik it's not possible to send structured data (lists of things) in formencoded  form fields. You could write your own parser, but this would brake the web view of your api. I'm using different endpoints for files and data now.