# Django-rest-framework Create object with relationship many-to many

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to create object "Tag" with relationship many-to-many attached to object "Task".I have this code and don't understand why it doesn't work. I see error Cannot resolve keyword 'task' into field. Choices are:  id, name, tags, 
P.S.
I relied on this post [manyToMany with django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828358/manytomany-with-django-rest-framework)

.models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)
```

.views

```
class TagCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        task_id = self.kwargs.get('task_id', None)
        if task_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(task=task_id)
        return queryset
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        task_id = self.kwargs.get('task_id', None)
        try:
            tasks = Task.objects.get(task__id__exact=task_id)
        except Task.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound()
        serializer.save(tag=tasks)
```

.serielizers

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name','')

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tags')
        read_only_fields = ('tags')
```

.urls

```
urlpatterns = {
url(r'^todolists/(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/tags', TagCreateView.as_view(), name="tags")}
```

Comment: `tag` field in `TaskSerializer` is marked as `read_only=True`, so how should it work, when it's readonly?

Comment: It's not a problem. If I change this type I see "Cannot resolve keyword 'task' into field" error.

Comment: Please fix the pasted code and error message. fields = ('id', 'name', '') makes no sense, the error you get doesn't match the code you pasted too meaning that you use a tag relation on the tag model..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle the nested serializers creation in the serializers `create` method;

As in here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

Comment: You don't have to handle nested representation, if you're okay with creating one record per HTTP [request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54222988/52499).

Answer (score 4):

If you're not hung up on creating intermediate and other table records in one HTTP request. Otherwise you've got to handle nested [representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45118730/52499).

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
import django.urls
import urllib

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return django.urls.reverse('app:product', args=(self.pk,))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Size(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=ProductVariant,
        related_name='sizes', related_query_name='size')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='productvariants', related_query_name='productvariant')
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='productvariants', related_query_name='productvariant')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('product', 'size')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product) + ': ' + str(self.size)
```

`api.py`:

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from app import models

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Size
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class SizeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Size.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SizeSerializer

class ProductVariantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=models.Product.objects.all())
    size = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=models.Size.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = models.ProductVariant
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'size')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class ProductVariantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.ProductVariant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductVariantSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', ProductViewSet)
router.register(r'sizes', SizeViewSet)
router.register(r'productvariants', ProductVariantViewSet)

api_urlpatterns = ([
    url('', include(router.urls)),
], 'api')
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urlpatterns)),
]
```

After that you can

```
POST /api/products/ {name: ...}
POST /api/sizes/ {name: ...}
POST /api/productvariants/ {product: productId, size: sizeId}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I will be showing many to many for update and create. The context is the event can have many dances and dances can have many event.

The request will be as followed.

```
 {
     "competition": 2,
     "title": "the title",
     "dances":[ {"id":1},{"id":2}],
     "description": "the desc"            
 }
```

The Create Function will be as followed.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        dance_ids = []
        for dance in self.initial_data['dances']:
            if 'id' not in dance:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'detail': 'key error'})
            dance_ids.append(dance['id'])

        new_event = models.Event.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        if dance_ids:
            for dance_id in dance_ids:
                new_event.dances.add(dance_id)
        new_event.save()
        return new_event

    except Exception as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'detail': e})
```

The Update Function will be as followed.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Delete all records of genres.
    try:
        for current_genre in instance.dances.all():
            instance.dances.remove(current_genre)

        # Repopulate genres into instance.
        for dance in self.initial_data['dances']:
            if 'id' not in dance:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'detail': 'key error'})
            dance_obj = models.Dance.objects.get(pk=dance['id'])
            instance.dances.add(dance_obj)

            event_updated = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        return event_updated
    except Exception as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'detail': e})
```

If you want to just do "dances":[1,2] instead, just make some amendments to the

```
for dance in self.initial_data['dances']:
        if 'id' not in dance:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'detail': 'key error'})
        dance_ids.append(dance['id'])
```

part.