# How to update Many to Many fields using PUT method in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following model and would like to create an update function in the serializers. The Http method i'm using is `PUT`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Model, which holds general employment information of an employee in an organization.
    """

    user = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    hr_number = models.CharField(verbose_name='HR number',blank=True, null=True,max_length=20, unique=True)

    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    unit = models.ManyToManyField(Unit)
```

So far this is my implementation of the update method.

```
class EmployeeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = DepartmentNameSerializer(many=True)
    unit = UnitNameSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields =  ['hr_number','department','unit']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        department_data = validated_data.pop('department')
        unit_data = validated_data.pop('unit')

        instance.hr_number = validated_data.get(
            'hr_number',
            instance.hr_number
        )

        department = instance.department
        for item in department_data:
            # item = dict(item)
            department.name = item.get('name',department.name)


        return instance
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-rest-framework Create object with relationship many-to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853588/django-rest-framework-create-object-with-relationship-many-to-many)

Comment: The link you provided is when creating many to many fields. My question is after you create them,how does one update them via the PUT method.

Comment: In the duplicate link, you'll find the link to the documentation where both `create` and `update` are described. But basically writing your own `update` method is the similar to `create` except you have to make some decisions on what to do with existing relations. [This link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

Comment: I've updated the code now I'm getting Attribute error: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: `department` is a `ManyToManyField` on your model (you should call it `departments` so you remember), so it can hold multiple objects. Therefore `department` in your update method is a `RelatedManager`. Also `item` is just a dict of the data you posted so you can't save it.