# How to make a ManyToMany serialization to be able to create a object in the POST request?

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serialize to handle a ManyToMany relation, but it's not working. I have read the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations) and I probably doing something wrong. Also I have read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853588/django-rest-framework-create-object-with-relationship-many-to-many).

Here are my models.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255)


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        related_name="id_author",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Price")


class FiscalDocument(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        related_name="user_id", 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

My serializer:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'price')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response['author'] = AuthorSerializer(instance.author).data
        return response

class FiscalDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = FiscalDocument
        fields = ('id', 'seller', 'book')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        book_data = validated_data.pop('book')
        fiscal_document = FiscalDocument.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Book.objects.create(FiscalDocument=FiscalDocument,**medicine_data)
        return fiscal_document
```

When I try to access the endpoint of the FiscalDocument, django-rest-framework is throwing an error:

`Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field price on serializer BookSerializer`. `The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the ManyRelatedManager instance.` `Original exception text was: ManyRelatedManager object has no attribute price.`
If anyone can help XD.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I'm using `viewsets.ModelViewSet`.

Comment: what is in your `medicine_data` and where do you declare that.  I have a feeling that `Book.objects.create(FiscalDocument=FiscalDocument,**medicine_data)` this line is not right.

Comment: Can you please show us the value of validated_data inside the create method of the FiscalDocumentSerializer?

Comment: Sorry, the name is not `medicine_data` is `book_data`, I changed the real names to post the question, my bad.

Comment: Show the value of validated_data, you mean with a `print(validated_data)`?