# Django Rest Framework: how to create and update many to many field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm finding a way to serialize model fields of a Many To Many relation object.
Models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    tag= models.ManyToManyField(Tag,
                                related_name='books',
                                blank=True)
```

Serializers -

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

Views -

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

I want to add the tag name to the response of the detailed view as well as the list view of books. If I try to create a serializer for the Tag model and use it in the book serializer, I'm not able to create or update the Book.

What should I do?
Also, is there a way to update only the tag field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django-rest-framework Create object with relationship many-to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853588/django-rest-framework-create-object-with-relationship-many-to-many)

Comment: @MahmoudAdel The above question doesn't clear the doubt. The above code returns a list of  PKs of the tags associated with the book. If I use a Tag serializer to populate the tag list in the BookSerializer, what should I add in the API request body of Book Create API to associate the tags with the Book. 
And how to create the Update API? Should I replace all the tags which are sent in the Update Request or Should I add the new Tags to the book and Create a Delete Tag view?

Comment: in update you should send the id's of tag in the request, then at `update()` you should get `tag` objects with this id and add them to the M2M relation

Comment: in create, you will pass the data of `tag` and use `TagSerializer` as you mentioned to validate and create that tag object or objects and link them to `Book`

Comment: see docs as it was mentioned in the answer I posted in my first comment, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The update method which you mentioned, can be used to add tags to the book, but how can I delete the tags? How can I delete one tag at a time from the book?

Comment: @MahmoudAdel Thank you for all the help. Found the solution to implement delete tag functionality.

Comment: great to hear, keep the good work up