# Django Rest Framework, creating a one-to-many field relationship between users and another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am trying to create a simple model which holds a number as the primary key (week number) and then a list of users. Thus the model should be something like this,

```
{
  id: 10,
  users: [
    user1,
    user2,
    ...
  ]
}
```

I am pretty sure I should do this with a one-to-many field. Thus I created the following model,

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    week = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, 
                                       unique=True,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(53)],
                                       )
    users = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name="users", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('week',)
```

What I want to happen is that if you do a POST request with an id and a list of users, then it simply creates the model. However if the id already exists, then it should simply clear the users, and add the newly given users instead. This is where I am stuck, I have tried the following (keeping comments in the code),

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True, queryset = MyUser.objects.all())

    # user_set = UserSerializer(many = True) 

    class Meta:
        model = Schema
        fields = ('week', 'users')

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     # users_data = validated_data.pop('users')
    #     schema = Schema.objects.create(**validated_data)
    #     # answer, created = Schema.objects.update_or_create(
    #     #     week=validated_data.get('week', 1),
    #     #     defaults={'users', validated_data.get('users', [])}
    #     # )
    #     return schema

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        users_data = validated_data.pop('users')
        instance.users.clear()
        instance.save()

        for user in users_data:
            instance.users.add(user)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Another problem I am running into is that, I don't know how the request expects the data, e.g, from Postman, I would think that it would only need the users id and of course the models id (week), however this is one of the things I have tried,

```
{
    "week": 32,
    "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.dk"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ForeignKey won't work for you. If one Schema object should have many relations with User model then you have to go with ManyToMany relationship([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)). So in yours model:

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    week = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, 
                                       unique=True,
                                       validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(53)],
                                       )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="users")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('week',)
```

for the part of update i think you need to pass user object not id to `add()`, so i would try:

```
 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        users_data = validated_data.pop('users')
        users = User.object.filter(id__in=user_data)
        instance.users.clear()
        instance.users.add(*users)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

for api view i recomend to read this thread on stack: [REST ManyToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37828358/13773284)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. But I guess I don't really see why OneToMany wouldn't work in this case. Since one schema has many users, or am I missing something? Also in my serializer would I then have to add something above my Meta class? As shown in my example?

Comment: After changing my model it now seems correct when looking in the Admin panel. However when I make the post request it says that I cannot call '.save()' on a serializer with invalid data

Comment: One schema has many users, but presumably one user can belong to many schemas (let's say, week 1 and week 23 for instance). So, many to many. Why is this object called `schema` when it has a week number as its primary key? Why not `week` instead? Schemas in database are, well, already something else called schemas. This will end up being confusing someday. Also you are locked into a single year of weeks so think about what happens after week 52 - if you don't have some plan for that already.

Comment: Right the ManyToMany model makes sense to me now. And I am aware that the naming might be a bit problematic. The way it works is that the user provides a week number, and I have applied two validators to the week number field which restricts it between 1 and 53. Thus week 1, might have some users attached, however then doing a new post request to week 1 should simply overwrite the current users attached to week 1. If that makes sense?