# Serialize related models and override the create method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF and I want to do something similar to the formsets in django forms
I have an `Invoice` And `Products` models related to each other throw a many to many `InvoiceDetail` model.. when I create an Invoice I choose some products and create a `InvoiceDetail` object for each .. I want to do this in DRF how can I serialize the Invoice model and it's create function then?
or should i do it form the view?

models.py:

```
 class Invoices(models.Model):
     #some fields
     products = models.ManyToManyField('Products', through='InvoiceDetail')


class Products(models.Model):
    #some fields


class InvoiceDetail(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoices, related_name='parent_invoice')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='parent_product')
    product_description = models.TextField()
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    quantity_sold = models.IntegerField()
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('barcode', 'product_code', 'name', 'description', 'category',
                  'quantity_in_stock', 'quantity_on_hold', 'expire_date',
                  'vendor', 'manufacturer', 'discount')


class InvoiceDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceDetail
        fields = '__all__'
```

view.py:

```
class ProductsView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Products.objects
    serializer_class = ProductsSerializer


class InvoicesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Invoices.objects
    serializer_class = InvoicesSerializer



class InvoiceDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = InvoiceDetail.objects
    serializer_class = InvoiceDetailsSerializer
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828358/manytomany-with-django-rest-framework and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759689/django-restframework-serializer-for-creating-m2m-relationship

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django restframework - Serializer for creating m2m relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759689/django-restframework-serializer-for-creating-m2m-relationship)

Comment: no my problem is different, I don't want to serialize the products field in `Invoice`, I want to create instances of another model `InvoiceDetail`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in the serializer itself,

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = [ f.name for f in model._meta.fields ] + ['products']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products = validated_data.pop('products')
        invoice = super(InvoiceSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        for product in products:
            InvoiceDetail.objects.create(invoice=invoice, product=product)
        return invoice
```

This, is just a basic example for to know about how this works. You could customise it however you need.

Comment: I got this error 
`<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f2e367dcd30> is not JSON serializable`  and how can i get the quantity sold form the client using this way?

Comment: You just need to add `many=True` in the products field. I totally forgot about it.

Comment: Edited my answer.